# Usage of the word parenthesis

Tags: word-usage

What does the word parenthesis mean? Does it mean **as an aside** or **in passing**. I looked at dictionary definition, but I could not understand its application **in the context of the sentence** below.

> I note in parenthesis that if a high earning household vacates a property, it may not, as the Croydon MP expected, be available to someone in greater need, because it may be deemed to be of higher value and have to be sold on the open market, possibly in London to a foreign buyer.

This sentence appears in the following link:

[Housing and Planning Bill - Report (3rd Day)](https://www.theyworkforyou.com/lords/?id=2016-04-18b.453.4)

Comment: Yes, either of them would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in parenthesis** is a phrase of the word the parenthesis.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/parenthesis):

> **in parenthesis** - *As a digression or afterthought.*

Digression means something that is not particularly needed in the context-of-speech and can be remarked as a brief sideline or departure from the main subject. That means this sentence was not entirely needed here, but he said it nonetheless. And yes, it can be termed as ***aside/s*** (noun).

Answer (score 2):

'In parenthesis' literally means 'in brackets', like (this). You place brackets round a phrase when it is intended as a comment 'by the way' and is not part of the main argument. Here, the writer just *says* that the note is 'in parenthesis' without actually putting it in brackets.